# CMS Collection not viewable to public or Community Plus Users. How can I change visibility?

Tags: community, knowledge, community-builder, lightning-knowledge

My Salesforce cohort are working on our Capstone project.  I am making at FAQ page at https://hawaiiunemployment-developer-edition.na156.force.com/homepage/s/faq?language=en_US.

I used CMS Collection to create a repository of Knowledge articles that could be dropped in via Builder.  When we published we discovered that the CMS Collection is not publicly available to view.  Community and Community Plus users can not view it either.  When we are logged in as a Standard User or System Administrator we can view it.

I have done quite a bit of Web and Trailblazers Answers searching for a solution to this issue.  I've tried going in and changing permissions for Knowledge.  None of it is really working.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score -1):

When working with Knowledge Articles in Salesforce CMS and communities (Experience Cloud), you'll want to check a few things:

- Knowledge is accessed via CRM connection & public list view: [Help: Salesforce CMS Now Supports Knowledge Articles](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_cms_knowledge_articles.htm&type=5&release=228)
- CMS Workspace has a publishing channel to your community: [Trailhead CMS Basics](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.community_builder_page_visibilty_overview.htm&type=5)
- CMS Collection visibility, if you select an audience make sure it includes the correct users / guests

I'd double check your list view settings, if all the other permissions look good.